# return value from .done to $this @ jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
control_td.each(function(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'control.php?udid='+$(this).attr('udid'),
  cache: false,
  async: true
}).done(function(data) {
  $(this).html(data);
});
});
```

but `$this` doesn't work in `.done` sub function. what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because `this` doesn't refer to the element item in the callback.

Try closing around a new value.

```
control_td.each(function(){
var $self = $(this); // magic here!
$.ajax({
  url: 'control.php?udid='+$(this).attr('udid'),
  cache: false,
  async: true
}).done(function(data) {
  $self.html(data);
});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
control_td.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'control.php?udid=' + $this.attr('udid'),
        cache: false,
        async: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        $this.html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also set the `context` option of the `$.ajax`, ***[check this option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)***.

```
control_td.each(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'control.php?udid='+$(this).attr('udid'),
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    context: this
  }).done(function(data) {
    $(this).html(data);
  });
});
```